# Refreshing a select menu

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have a jquery-ui-selectmenu (jquery-ui-1.11.0pre) with only one option in it (for now). Now when i change the text of that value in the original select element i'll have to refresh the selectmenu element. So i do:

```
$jq("#selectMenu").first().text("newText");
$jq("#selectMenu").selectmenu("refresh");
```

It seems that now the text of the new option actually changed (in the dropdown menu) but the select value that i see on the button is not updated it is still the old value. How can i fix this?

Comment: What about $jq("#selectMenu").selectmenu() instead of refresh?

Comment: this does not have any effect either

Comment: It can't. Wrong API for this version.